# Recharts - bar chart dynamic label position

Tags: reactjs, recharts

How can I have dynamic label positions of Bars like is showing in the picture?

[image]

Here is my code till now

```
const data = [
        { currency: 'CHF', amount: 3, amountLabel: 3023.00 },
        { currency: 'GBP', amount: 6, amountLabel: 6275.00 },
        { currency: 'USD', amount: 10, amountLabel: 9999.00 },
        { currency: 'EUR', amount: 14, amountLabel: 14819.00 },
        { currency: 'LEK', amount: 24, amountLabel: 24023000.00 },
    ];    
<BarChart
    width={430}
    height={170}
    data={data}
    layout="vertical">
    <XAxis type="number" orientation="top" stroke="#285A64" />
    <YAxis type="category" dataKey="currency" axisLine={false} dx={-5} tickLine={false} 
           style={{ fill: "#285A64" }} />
     <Bar background dataKey="amount" fill="#285A64" barSize={{ height: 26 }}>
        <LabelList dataKey="amountLabel" position="insideRight" style={{ fill: "white" }} />
     </Bar>
</BarChart>
```

Find Sample code here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JonaDushi/u721se46/)

Comment: As you said this example is having a dynamic label positioning. That is true. What do you need?

Comment: As you can see in the image the position of the label is dynamic. Some bars have it `position: "right", color :"black"` and the last one has `position:"insideRight", color:"white"`

Comment: Yeah.I see last bar label is inside the bar because of it's css. and the other have label outer the bar.

Comment: I haven't been able to achieve that. Please see the code example. What am I missing?

Comment: I replaced you code samples with the original code and there were nothing wrong in your code sample. I have a feeling about there is something wrong with the versions you are using or there can be overridden CSS for the bar. Are you using rechart in another page of your app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should implement a React component to be injected into the prop `content` (LabelList)

For example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mn8bdo3k/)):

```
const {BarChart, Bar, XAxis, YAxis, LabelList} = Recharts;
 const data = [
        { currency: 'CHF', amount: 3, amountLabel: 3023.00 },
        { currency: 'GBP', amount: 6, amountLabel: 6275.00 },
        { currency: 'USD', amount: 10, amountLabel: 9999.00 },
        { currency: 'EUR', amount: 14, amountLabel: 14819.00 },
        { currency: 'LEK', amount: 26, amountLabel: 26023000.00 },
    ];
    
const renderCustomizedLabel = (props) => {
  const {
    x, y, width, height, value,
  } = props;

const fireOffset = value.toString().length < 5;
const offset = fireOffset ? -40 : 5;
  return (
      <text x={x + width -offset} y={y + height - 5} fill={fireOffset ? "#285A64" :"#fff"} textAnchor="end">
        {value}
      </text>
  );
};

const VerticalBarChart = React.createClass({
    render () {
    return (
        <BarChart
                width={400}
                height={170}
                data={data}
                layout="vertical">
                <XAxis type="number" orientation="top" stroke="#285A64"/>
                <YAxis type="category" dataKey="currency" axisLine={false} dx={-10} tickLine={false} style={{ fill: "#285A64" }} />
                <Bar background dataKey="amount" fill="#285A64" barSize={{ height: 26 }}>
                    <LabelList dataKey="amountLabel" content={renderCustomizedLabel} position="insideRight" style={{ fill: "white" }} />
                </Bar>
            </BarChart>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <VerticalBarChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Commenting to say that this was a really helpful post and I used this solution! Thank you for sharing!

Comment: The fiddle provided no longer works.